# Does multiple thread help if Fragment Shader takes too long to execute?

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es

Currently I'm working on an image process algorithm on Android using OpenGL ES.  The size of the input image is quite large (like 4000x6000 pixels) and the algorithm requires multiply iterations.  In my implementation, I wrote the code in   the fragment shader and set an FBO texture to proform render-to-texture stuff.

However, it takes nearly 2~3 seconds.  During that time, the UI layer which is also rendering using OpenGL ES freezes.  Users can not interact with it.  Before optimize the shader code, I wonder if GPU can run two shaders simultaneously.

So, How can I keep my UI active?  Do I need multiple context that one context to render UI and the other to perform render-to-texture shader?

Comment: Some GPU can execute different shaders simultaneously, but it's bad idea to rely on it. In your case it'll be much better to divide work from your shader and do only one step at frame. For example, you can divide your input image to pieces and process only one at once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a pretty standard procedure. You need to put that process into a separate thread which also mens creating a new context.

To receive the data (a texture for instance) from a second context and use it in your main context you will need to look into the shared context. If you will not create a shared context then there should be no way to transfer data from one context to another.

The number of additional threads you will open depends on what you are doing but usually it is safest to have only one background thread. So basically you would want to create a worker which will run in another thread and you can assign tasks to it. You will need to watch out how you handle the callbacks from the workers though, multithreading can easily produce issues.